# Reading CoreAudio input level with Tascam US-144MKII

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, volume

(this is a clearer version of a question asked recently)

I'm taking over some code to fix some problems, and one of them is baffling me.

The application needs to monitor the input level and display it so that the user can adjust if needed.  The current code works perfectly with most devices.  Metering mode is enabled, and these two lines are called by a timer routine and work- except with one device:

```
AudioUnitGetParameter(mMixerUnit, k3DMixerParam_PreAveragePower, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &levels[0]);
AudioUnitGetParameter(mMixerUnit, k3DMixerParam_PrePeakHoldLevel, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &peaks[0]);
```

When the selected input device is a Tascam US-144MKII, the value is always -120 for both level and peak.  There are a few differences with the Tascam unit, for example, it lists 4 channels and has a safety offset of 0.  However, I don't see how either of those would cause this particular problem.  Right now my guess is that there is something in the USBAudio drivers from Tascam that is doing things differently than expected.

Volumes do show up using Audacity, but if I'm reading the code correctly, Audacity is using deprecated functions.  Is it possible to run a separate AudioQueue, not to capture the data, but simply so that I can grab the input levels?

I appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

When the Tascam unit is selected as the input, the input callback in the code never gets called.  The exact reasons for that are not yet defined, but essentially it's not just getting volume levels, nothing is working when the Tascam unit is selected as the input device.